# Two NICs: if one is unplugged both go down

Tags: networking, server, network-bridge

I bought a new PCI network card so that I could have two NICs in my home 'server' because I want to be able to run a gateway on a VM between my internet and my lan.

I have my internal LAN interface eth0 and my to-be external interface eth1.

The config in /etc/network/interfaces is:

```
auto eth0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_maxwait 5
```

My current gateway gives out IPs and always assigns br0 as 10.1.1.2 and as I'm testing the new interface it has been assigned 10.1.1.7

The problem is that when I unplug eth1 (physically) both interfaces go down and become unpingable even though eth0 (or br0) is still connected.

Looking at dmesg only shows eth1 going down as expected but nothing is shown for the bridge or eth0.

```
[  936.509077] r8169 0000:06:00.0 eth1: link down
[  945.789768] r8169 0000:06:00.0 eth1: link up
```

I'm at a loss to what is happening, any advise would be much appreciated.

Edit: Made some progress, I made eth1 have its own bridge so the config now looks like this:

```
auto eth0
auto eth1

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_maxwait 5

auto br1
iface br1 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports eth1
  bridge_maxwait 5
```

I can now disconnect the physical connection from eth1 and eth0 remains up, however! It seems that when I disconnect eth1 physically, I can still ping its IP if eth0 remains connected. Again, this seems to be weird voodoo or perhaps I'm miss understanding how linux routing works internally.